# DSP implementation recommended bibliography (good books-material related to fixed/floating point-optimization)

Tags: dsp-core, fixed-point, floating-point

I am doing my first steps in embedded systems and there is a big deal of fixed point code and of course DSP optimized code.I would like please if possible to recommend any book/material related to that topics.

Comment: This question is way too general and/or going to be too prone to opinionated (rather than fact-based) answers. Hence, we've put it on hold.